# Taylor Series of x^(1/2) at a=1

Tags: calculus

Im having big trouble with this one ive compared answers with peers and everyone seems to have something different, any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+sqrt%28x%29+at+x%3D1&lk=4&num=1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for $(x-1)^{1/2}$.